# Не работает onclick с таймером

Tags: javascript, safari

Есть событие onclick, который некорректно работает на Safari. После перехода и возвращения на страницу, ссылка перестает работать.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="url=this.href;setTimeout('location.href=url',600);this.href='javascript:void(0)';">cсылка</a>
```

Есть такой скрипт, но почему то он совсем не работает:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="url=this.href; setTimeout('location.href='+url, 600); return false;">cсылка</a>
```

Есть ли рабочий скрипт задержки перехода по ссылке, который работает корректно на всех браузерах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="#" 
  onclick="var linkUrl=this.href;setTimeout(function(){location.href=linkUrl;},600);return false;"
>cсылка</a>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @МаксимТянин Пожалуйста. Успехов.